# Trying to make a bot that sends DMs to users

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm attempting to make a discord bot that checks messages sent in channels for a prefix and argument (!send @Usermention "message"), but despite running, the program closes out as soon as a message is typed in my discord server, not outputting any error messages, so I'm not really sure what to do...

```
       const Discord = require('discord.js');
       const client = new Discord.Client();
       const auth = require('./auth.json');
       const prefix = "!";

       client.on("message", (message) => 
       {
           msg = message.content.toLowerCase();

           if (message.author.bot) { return; }
           mention = message.mention.users.first(); //gets the first mention of the user's message

           if (msg.startsWith (prefix + "send")) //!send @name [message]
           {
               if (mention == null) { return; } //prevents an error sending a message to nothing
               message.delete();
               mentionMessage = message.content.slice (6); //removes the command from the message to be sent
               mention.sendMessage (mentionMessage); //sends message to mentioned user
               message.channel.send ("message sent :)");
           }
       });
       client.login(auth.token);
```

Comment: If you ever want to see any errors wrap what youre running in try catch block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mention = message.mention.users.first();`
It is [`message.mention**s**`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=mentions).  You were missing an `s`.

Also, you might want to use [`send`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=send), rather than `sendMessage`, since `sendMessage` is deprecated.

Comment: +1 I appreciate this a lot, I had no idea what I had done wrong. I had initially used .send, but since it didn't work, thought it might have been sendmessage instead. After testing this, I see that it works. Thank you :)